# Cannot open SQLite3 database with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I have not tried the following code with some success without PDO:

```
 <html><body>
    <?php
    $db = new sqlite3('/home/harry/interface/wildlife.db');
    
    $results = $db->query('SELECT cascade FROM animalStream');
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
    ?>
    </body></html>
```

It shows relevent data without throwing errors, but the format is like this:

```
 string(9) "otter.xls" ["cascade"]=> string(9) "otter.xls" } array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "primate.xls" ["cascade"]=> string(11) "primate.xls" } array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "junglecat.xls" ["cascade"]=> string(13) "junglecat.xls" } array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "pangalin.xls" ["cascade"]=> string(12) "pangalin.xls" }
```

So it wants to work, it is just getting it to format correctly.  Does any one have any ideas about that?  Thank you!

Comment: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1) Is the SQLite3 extension enabled?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  No, I have not enabled the SQLite3 extension.   I am checking on that now.  I am using lighttpd as a server.

Comment: I have modified the php.ini file by un-commenting the following two lines:

extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so    But no joy yet.

Comment: Restarted your server? Does the extension show as enabled in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: No, it does not show up as enabled or disabled.  Just shows the author's names.  This is in the php.ini file: [sqlite3]
; Directory pointing to SQLite3 extensions
; http://php.net/sqlite3.extension-dir
;sqlite3.extension_dir =      Trying to find an explanation for it.

Comment: I am unclear as to what is suppose to go here: sqlite3.extension_dir = ""     Sqlite is showing up all over my phpinfo.php, but still getting a blank page.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): Argument #1 ($dsn) must be a valid data source name in /var/www/html/index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(8): PDO->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 8

Comment: It seems to work now.  I replaced   /var_dump($row);  with $row=(implode(",", $row)); and it works.  It produces two comma delimited outputs per line, otter.xls,otter.xls  , but that can be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now. I replaced /var_dump($row); with $row=(implode(",", $row)); and it works. It produces two comma delimited outputs per line, otter.xls,otter.xls , but that can be dealt with.